# match every character until a pattern occurs in the beginning of the line (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text:

```
<a>
    a lot of text here with all types of symbols ! : . %& < >
</a>

<a>
    another text here with all types of symbols ! : . %& < >
</a>
```

I want to match the tag name and its contents: so the procedure I'm using is match:

```
<([^]*?)>(?:([^]*)<\/\1>)?
```

NOTE: I use the conditional group at the end because it can be omitted, for example.

```
<a>

<a>
    another text here with all types of symbols ! : . %& < >
</a>
```

But my problem is that the regex tries to consume every character so it opens and closes the tab and the contents of the tab becomes:

```
<a>
    another text here with all types of symbols ! : . %& < >
```

when I wanted to detect two matches one the isolated tag and the other the multiline tag.

NOTE2: This is NOT HTML or XML so I don't need to parse it like wise.
NOTE3: my ideia was to replace the regex part:

```
(?:([^]*)....
```

by something that would 'match every character until '<' appears at the beginning of the line (this because in the text I'm parsing there can't be tags inside tags) so I thought that would be good.. but I can't seem to find a regex for that :(

Comment: Just curious, any reason why you're using `[^]` instead of `.`?

Comment: Don't use regexps to analyze HTML. HTML isn't that *regular* to use regexps. Parse the whole HTML and traverse it using regular DOM, and then use regexps to match element text content.

Comment: I use [^] because I want it to match multiline... . matches every character until new line. I'm creating a game in javascript and sometimes I want to pass extra data between the editor and the engine itself... and I use tags for that. Is there a better/faster way to parse tags in javascript it self? thank you

Comment: Check my _edited_ answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is `/<([a-z0-9-]+)>([^]*?)(?:(<\/\1>)|$|(?=(?:<[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+>)))/gi`

Comment: but if there are multine tags they wont match!! :(

Comment: I've modified my answer.

Comment: Ohhh my god!! you did it! :O

Comment: Thanks to a little help from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions (regex lookahead)

Comment: Why did you add the $ sign in the alternative statement?

Comment: (?:(<\/\1>)|$|(?=(?:<[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+>))) - Match either 1. `(<\/\1>)` closing tag, 2. `$` end of string, or 3. `(?=(?:<[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+>))` just before the beginning of a new tag. The `$` makes it match the end of the string (in case there is no closing tag till the end)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you parse it by program:

1. Match the first occurrence of any opening tag:
   `<([a-z0-9]+)>`
   With this, you can get the tag's name.
2. Get the position of the second occurrence of any opening tag and the position of the first ocurrence of the closing tag with the same name that the read before.
3. Compare these positions and decide if it was a single-line just-open-tag or a multi-line open-and-close-tag.
4. Get the content enclosed between the first opening tag and the lowest position got in step 2.

Comment: that would bem a good ideia but.. I was looking for a 'magic Regex' for doing this.. I'm not a Regex expert and as there are a lot of pros here I thought I would ask! But I'm afraid that is my best option.